# Predicting team performance

Tags: machine-learning, games

Are there any Machine Learning/ Datamining research paper which deals with predicting the performance of two team containing each $x$ players?

Comment: Can you add some details?

Comment: Which game?  If there is no interaction in the players then changing "x" does no good.  Need more information before this can be answered.

Answer (score 1):

[Microsoft's TrueSkill](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/trueskill/) rating system handles team games composed of arbitrary sets of players.